# How to make files optional in giter8

Tags: scala, sbt, giter8

In giter8, it is possible to change the content of files based on user input, ie (from the [docs](http://www.foundweekends.org/giter8/template.html#Conditionals)):

```
$if(scala212.truthy)$
scalaVersion := "2.12.3"
$elseif(scala211.truthy)$
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"
$else$
scalaVersion := "2.10.6"
$endif$
```

Is it possible to create some files on certain conditions as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible at the moment (v0.10.0), but there is an open issue for that: [foundweekends/giter8#345](https://github.com/foundweekends/giter8/issues/345). You can add your opinion and usecase there. You're also welcome to contribute an implementation for this feature.